# Asteroid/comet deflection: Will a stream of nukes work?

Tags: science-based, technology, nuclear-weapons, asteroids, propulsion

Imagine you want to change the course of an asteroid quickly. You have huge resources at your disposal. What is the best way to move an asteroid quickly? Consider different compositions, chiefly solid iron-nickel, a collection of pebbles and a lump of ice.

I know about gravity tractors, but the are slow. If I had a lot of nukes at hand, would shooting them in a steady stream towards the asteroid (or the position where it will be when the nuke ad the rock meet) be a good strategy to change its course?

I know that letting the nukes impact the rock will only result in smaller fragments (which might also do if it will impact earth and you are really in a hurry), but I want yo redirect or even capture the thing. Installing a drive on the rock would be hard, especially if it isn't well known structurally and gas a high relative velocity.

However there is the good old [Casaba Howitzer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casaba-Howitzer) if we Weare to steadyly bombard the rock with these, would that change its course effectively? Or are there better and faster options?

Comment: The problem will always be that you won’t know the exact composition of the rock hurtling towards you. I’m sure throwing bombs at it would be perfectly acceptable if you were able to draw up a mathematical model showing what those nukes will actually do but such a model is nigh-on impossible to provide, hence any reluctance to even try nukes; weapon which, by their nature, will limit your options for Plan B. Besides, I suspect that despite its epic power a nuke would rather expand into the void of space than through the enormous boulder pressing against it.

Comment: @DariusArcturus 1. "Besides, I suspect that despite its epic power a nuke would rather expand into the void of space than through the enormous boulder pressing against it" - that's why I want use Casaba Howitzers. These are nuclear powered particle beams. 2. Once the first few nukes hit, we will learn how the asteroid reacts. From there on we adjust yields (modern nukes can do that)  and frequency (better launch more than you need, so the planning committee should assume the worst case scenario.)

Comment: Worth noting, you have to divert the impactor, it's irrelevant if you break it up or not. If it breaks up, you still have to ensure those pieces aren't largely captured by earths gravity anyway. Why? Because the damage and heat arises from the kinetic energy of X tons of matter falling through earths gravity well. That energy needs to go somewhere, and it doesn't matter if it arrives in big bits or small, one or many.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a stream of nukes would work.

https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/how-to-stop-a-killer-asteroid

They did the calculations. You could send a stream of Saturn Vs with nukes on to detonate 20 meters above the surface.

> “The experiments show, first and foremost, that we can generate X-rays at a level sufficient to deliver the equivalent of a hammer blow to an object,” says Lawrence. More specifically, they found that the motion induced by a blast was consistent for a given class of materials, such as stony versus metallic meteorites. “If we know from reconnaissance that it’s a stony asteroid or a nickel-iron asteroid,” explains Remo, “we can have a pretty good idea in advance how it will respond to an X-ray blast.”

In addition, Remo would like to see a comprehensive review of all the components needed for this option: the launch vehicles, guidance systems, sensors and cradle holding the nuclear explosives. A 2007 paper he helped write recommended six nuclear missiles, released individually at intervals of about an hour. The bombs would go off in six separate blasts, each with a yield of up to 1.2 megatons (equivalent to about 100 Hiroshima-scale bombs).

> With a series of separate pulses, Remo says, you could monitor the effects, making adjustments as you go along. Having several smaller explosions instead of one really big blast also reduces the chances of fragmenting the asteroid, which would make it more difficult to handle, Remo adds. “We want to give it just the right amount of energy — enough to give it a good kick but not so much that you break it into bits.”

Answer (score 1):

**Conventional explosives would work better.**

Consider a nuclear explosion on Earth.  Matter turns into energy and lots of it.  The consequent destruction is because the radiant energy heats the atmosphere into a hot fast moving wall of gas that wipes out everything in its path.

In space, the energy has nothing to heat up and just "expands into the void of space" as @Darius Arcturus put it.  Wasted.  If you could get the nuke deep into the asteroid before it went off you could heat the stuff of the asteroid into gas and that ejecting material would go in the direction the rocket came from and impart a vector force, either slowing or changing the course of the asteroid.  But a nuclear missile hitting an asteroid at speed might just break.  They can be fragile.  You might need Bruce Willis to land and dig the bomb into the asteroid and be ready to nobly die to save us all but it turns out ok.

If Bruce refuses, better would be to hit it with conventional explosives.  Most explosives turn their components into gas when they blow up and so you are assured of a cloud of gas pushing on the asteroid.  It is not hard to make an explosive that blows up when it hits.

Other musings:
https://www.halfbakery.com/idea/Gust_20of_20wind_20asteroid_20diverter#1330469215

Comment: Do you know what a Casaba Howitzer does? It is a nuclear pumped particle beam. It solves the issues nukes have in space.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight - where would you shoot it from?  If you can fly up to the asteroid and hold position, park on the asteroid with your cannon, clip it on, and you now have a nuclear engine to steer it around.   Which you said would be hard so I did not consider.

Comment: If the nuke was placed on the asteroid & detonated the heat of the explosion would vaporize the asteroid if it was small enough & partially vaporize it if it was huge.

Comment: @Fred maybe. Depends on the material. But you'd not get the blast effect that many people associate with nuclear weapons as the main force, is the point here.

Comment: The reason for nukes is that the boom per pound is so much higher.  A simple standoff detonation of a nuke can get 10% energy transfer, the Casaba Howitzer approach can get 50% or more.  10% of a nuke is far better than 100% of conventional explosives (not that you would get 100% anyway) and besides a plain old solid rocket motor will do better than explosives.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "one solution fits all" scenario, much depends on the size and composition of the asteroid. For example: explosives (nuclear or conventional) may create a more dangerous situation by splitting an asteroid which then multiplies the problem of trajectory prediction.

NASA and other organizations have created a range of Collision Avoidance Strategies:

- Nuclear explosive device

  - Stand-off approach
  - Surface and subsurface use
  - Comet deflection possibility
- Kinetic impact
- Asteroid gravity tractor
- Ion beam shepherd
- Focused solar energy
- Mass driver
- Conventional rocket engine
- Asteroid laser ablation

For details, see [Collision Avoidance Strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_impact_avoidance#Collision_avoidance_strategies)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no time for a proper deflection the hard decision would be to try and break it up. With many smaller fragments you can't avoid a meteor shower hitting the Earth, but the damage would be less than a full big impact. Piercing missiles can burrow deep into the rock and the heat of the explosions would turn the ice trapped inside in hot gases that will propel part of the mass away, so the rock could be deflected using its own material.

Comment: Doesn't work. The damage and heat arises from the kinetic energy of X tons of matter falling through earths gravity well. That energy needs to go somewhere, and it doesn't matter if it arrives in big bits or small, one or many. The idea here that small bits will just fade and die if a big bit breaks up, is flawed. Sorry. Fails.

Comment: @Stilez you are assuming that the fragment would behave like a liquid drop staying close together even after one or two months travelling in space. Is your assumption that is flawed.

Comment: No. It doesn't matter how it behaves and breaks up.  The only thing that matters is how much of the dust and debris is diverted away from earth enough to never be captured. If you don't divert enough, then add up whatever amount is eventually captured onto earth, and the heat released will be about the same as a single unbroken asteroid of that mass.  I make no assumptions about how it behaves, just that you have to divert. Breaking up alone is no good. Doesn't help.

Comment: No--blast radius goes up at the third root of energy.  Area goes up at the square of radius.  Thus the destroyed area goes at the 2/3 root of energy.  Split a rock into 8 equal fragments and you double the damage.  (Not to mention with a big enough boom a lot of blast energy doesn't follow the curvature of the Earth.)  You only want to disrupt the small ones where you can blow them into fragments that will burn in the atmosphere.

Comment: Since both of you seem so knowledgeable in physics and maths I'll give you a small problem. The asteroid is travelling at 60000 Km per hour and at the moment of the impact is two months from the Earth. What was the distance? A nuclear bomb pushed by a piercing rocket explodes 3 meters below the surface. How much mass is pushed in a direction and how much in the other? When they reach the Earth, travelling the distance resulting from the first calculation what is the approximate divergence (or distance between the two masses that were separated)?

Answer (score 0):

Nuke delivers **far** more energy per pound and that's the important thing here--a deflection mission is going to be limited by how much we can throw.

Nuke also has the advantage that if your guidance system is good enough you don't have to expend delta-v to rendezvous--the relative velocity between bomb and asteroid makes no meaningful difference in the impulse delivered.  Weight not used on rendezvous fuel is weight that can be used to carry more boom.

You need to watch the impulse delivered per boom, keep it well below escape velocity so if your target comes apart it will reform rather than disperse.  You also need to allow enough time between booms for it to reform.  Obviously, that's not important if you **know** you're dealing with a single solid object, but unless you're a mining crew on the asteroid who has plenty of time to study the rock that's not something you can expect to know.